# \end{align*} not in math environment

Tags: equations

As I'm fairly new to LaTeX, I was hoping someone could help me out. Using the apa6 document format, with amsmath imported, I tried to compile the following code:

```
\[\text{A} = B * \text{log}\frac{C}{D} \\
\text{where} \begin{align*}
 & C = \text{lorem} \\
 & D = \text{ipsum}
end{align*}\]
```

This throws the following errors:
[image: Errors in Texmaker]

Could anyone give me an indicator on how to solve this or why this happens?

Comment: You cannot have align (a math environment) inside a math environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `aligned` environment:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{apa6}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathrm{A} = B * \log\frac{C}{D}, \qquad
  \text{where}\quad
  \begin{aligned}
    C &= \text{lorem} \\
    D &= \text{ipsum}
 \end{aligned}
\]

\begin{gather*}
  \mathrm{A} = B * \log\frac{C}{D}, \\
  \text{where}\quad
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    C &= \text{lorem} \\
    D &= \text{ipsum}
 \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

`align*` is a top level math environment to be used instead of `\[...\]`.

Note that `\[...\]` does not accept the line break command `\\` (at least it has no effect), so if you want to the conditions on a separate line use either `gather*` (as in my second example) or `align*`.

Additionally you should

- use `\log` for the log operator
- use `\mathrm{A}` to get an upright `A`

Part of the reason is that `\text` will change font according to the surrounding text and you do not want that to happen in the maths.

I also strongly suspect you do not want to have the `*` multiplication symbol and should just `B \log ...`.  But that is a question of your style.

Answer (score 2):

As you cannot use `align*` inside `\[....\]` you probably want to use an `array` environment, so that your code will look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

  \[A = B * \log\frac{C}{D}, \qquad
  \text{ where } \begin{array}{ll}
                   C &= \text{lorem} \\
                   D &= \text{ipsum}
                 \end{array}
  \]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Personally, I would omit the `*` and write `A = B\log\frac{C}{D}`. In particular, I have used:

- `\log` instead of `\text{log}`
- `A` instead of `\text{A}` (since `A` is part of the mathematics, not the text)
- `\qquad` to put some space between the equation and `where`

and that it is normally better to put the alignment character `&` before the equal signs rather than before the whole equation.

Another option would be to use a `cases` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

  \[A = B * \log\frac{C}{D}, \qquad
  \text{ where } \begin{cases}
                   C = \text{lorem} \\
                   D = \text{ipsum}
                 \end{cases}
  \]

\end{document}
```

to give

[image]

As Bernard pointed out in the comments, it is better not to use alignment in the cases environment.

Finally, when asking questions it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).  A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Adding a MWE clarifies your question and makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: I wouldn't put any  ampersand in the cases environment: why add a  horizontal spacing?

Comment: @Bernard Good point. I agree. Will edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, learned a lot by your post(s?)! Next time I will provide a MWE :-)